# Rewrite URL : remove sub folders and file extension from URL

Tags: php, regex, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am trying to remove .php file extension and folder && subfolder from URL if they exist.

**Case 1**

**Input:**

```
127.0.0.1/project/folder/alfa.php
```

**output:**

```
127.0.0.1/project/alfa
```

**Case 2**

**Input:**

```
127.0.0.1/project/folder/subfolder/beta.php
```

**Output:**

```
127.0.0.1/project/beta
```

**Here is what I have got so far :**

Removing just extension works fine, having problem with removing folders

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^((?! folder/).+?)/?$ folder/ [L,NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Please advice
Thanks.

Comment: I think you need hard code the project dir.

Comment: Do you mean to mask or redirect? Ie, is the scenario that I visit `127.0.0.1/project/folder/subfolder/beta.php` and get redirected to `127.0.0.1/project/beta`, or are you trying to have users visit `127.0.0.1/project/beta` as a mask for `127.0.0.1/project/folder/subfolder/beta.php`?

Comment: @Bananaapple
trying to have users visit 127.0.0.1/project/beta as a mask for 127.0.0.1/project/folder/subfolder/beta.php

Comment: so what if there are 2 folders and 3-4 subfolders? how you determine to which folder you should redirect them?

Comment: `127.0.0.1/project/beta` can be rewritten to `127.0.0.1/project/folder/subfolder/beta.php` but then similar `127.0.0.1/project/alfa` cannot be rewritten to `127.0.0.1/project/folder/alfa.php`

Comment: @anubhava  Folder depth is only 2 ie folder and subfolder and all files in each folder is unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have this .htaccess inside `/project/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/

# rewrite to folder/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/project/folder/subfolder/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ folder/subfolder/$1.php [L]

# rewrite to folder/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/project/folder/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ folder/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: absolutely perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex to capture  the required fields from URL. Then use captured values 1, 2 to generate the output.

```
([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\/[A-Za-z0-9]*).*(\/.*)\.php
```

You can see the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/x5785b/1) here. It captures the address and parent folder in 1 and filename in 2.

Note : I have considered the address to be ipv4

Comment: Thanks ! I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification in your comment on your question - this will be hard to handle dynamically via `RewriteRule` alone.

Consider this:

How is Apache to know that `/project/beta` maps to `/project/folder/subfolder/beta.php` while `/project/alfa` maps to `/project/folder/alfa.php`?

You could hardcode these like so:

`RewriteRule ^project/beta/? /project/folder/subfolder/beta.php [QSA,L]`

`RewriteRule ^/project/alfa/? /project/folder/alfa.php [QSA,L]`

If this isn't feasible due to a large number of rules that would be required here I would attempt to solve this via a script. Something like this:

If the requested resource is not a file or directory send it to a script. Then have the script search a target directory structure such as `/project` for all php files that match the second portion of your masked URL (the alfa / beta part). If only one file is found require it in order to run it.

Comment: Folder depth is only 2 ie folder and subfolder and all files in each folder is unique . If thats make it easier