# Hide part of URL with RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have an URL

```
domain.de/pages/mysite.php
```

witch I want to change into

```
 domain.de/mysite.php
```

using Apache and .htaccess.
I've tried this but it isn't working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)/pages/(.*) $1/$2 [L]
```

This worked neither:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$1.php [L]
```

Comment: The two URLs are identical.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewrite URL : remove sub folders and file extension from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710824/rewrite-url-remove-sub-folders-and-file-extension-from-url)

Comment: Didn't worked out for me...

Comment: What error do you get if you type `domain.de/mysite.php` into your browser ?

Comment: just a 404 - "not found".

Comment: Replace your RewriteRule line with this : `RewriteRule !pages /pages%{REQUEST_URI} [L]`

Comment: Also not working. Is `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}pages/$1.php -f` correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this worked out for me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.de$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/
RewriteRule (.*) /pages/$1
```

Further I've added it directly into the virtual host config, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618326/mod-rewrite-hide-folder).